# Load a piece of html in a jQuery tab using jQuery AJAX on Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter, tabs

I'm here because I can't load a piece oh html code (a form that contain the client's data) in a JQuery tabs, using JQuery AJAX. 
I tried to use JQuery .load(), .append() .html(), but I can't load a simple html form in a JQuery tab.
I use **codeigniter** and in the controller there are some function: 
one of this named ***findClient*** create a CI pagination, that had a table that contain a radio input.

```
class Management extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->library('myclients');
    session_start();
}


function index($clientsFound=0){
      ...
  ...       
}


public function findCliente(){
    // generate a pagination, in a table. each row have a radio, 
    // and hads a rispective id of that record
}
```

When I click on the submit button, in a tab-1....
I call a JQuery AJAX

```
$('#fm_submit_report').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var form_data = {
                id_client: $('input:checked').val(),
                ci_csrf_token: $.cookie("ci_csrf_token")
            };
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'management/createReport',
                type: 'POST',
                async : false,
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(dati, stato){
                    $('#tabs').tabs('select',4);
                    alert('Creation of a Report');
                    console.log('stato: '+stato+'   received data: '+dati);
                    $('#create_report').load(dati);
                    alert('end of load');
                },
                error: function(xhr) {

                var message = 'Errore nell\'invio del form: ';
                var status = xhr.status;
                var text = xhr.statusText;

                message += status + ': ' + text;

                $('<div class="error"/>').text(message).
                appendTo(form);

                }
            });
            return false;
```

This ajax, pass the cient id, to the method ***createReport()***. As U can see, this method, get the client informations using *myclients* library, and after pass this information, in a "*piece of html code*" to create a form with the client data inside

```
public function createReport(){
    $client=$this->myclients->findClientById($this->input->post('id_cliente'));
    $data['client'] = $client;
 // this is a client information to pass in the view to generate the form, that will load in a tab

   $hthmlcode=$this->load->view('create_report', $data);
   // create_view is the html form 

 echo $htmlcode;
}

}/* End of function createReport */
```

The html code to load in a JQuery tab is this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>                                                         
        <table style="margin-top:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <?php echo form_open('management/storeReport') ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="report_left"><h2>Visit Date</h2></td>
                <td class="report_dx"><?php echo form_input('data_visita', '', 'class="data", id="datepickervisita"'); ?></td>
            </tr>
            [ ...cut ...]
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php echo form_input($btnInviaReport); ?>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        <div class="error_report"></div>
    </td>  
</tr>    
</table>
</div>
```

But unfortunately the code in html was not loaded in the 5th tabs... and the post return the entire page (instead my html form) !!!

I noticed, in firebug console,that the path of *controller/method* that I set in the url of ajax, is wrong, in fatc i set

```
url: 'management/createReport'
```

but in the console i see that the post is send to this address:

```
http://_local_ip_/management/management/createReport
```

but, obviously, if I don't set the controller (just set url:'createReport'), the return variable "dati" will be empty, because I call a method of an undefined controller

```
success: function(dati, stato)
```

I suspect, that my *.htaccess* file is the cause of this trouble (why the name of controller is repeated twice, when the ajax is called ???)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    RewriteRule ^(system|application) - [F,L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^public.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

public is the folder of my project, and it's outside of system directory ...

Comment: Can you rule out the typo?: `$thmlcode=$this->load->view('create_report', $data); echo $htmlcode;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
The problem was the url entry in the JQuery AJAX function, infact instead of

```
 url: 'management/createReport',
```

I create a function in my library ***Myjavascript/getSubmitRadio()***, that take a string passed to controller, and return the entire JQuery function. The JQuery function is a string that I pass to the header view

```
 // -=[ Get the javascript code to insert in the header, to esecute a JQuery Submit on a specified form ]=-    
   $submitReportForm = $this->myjavascript->getSubmitRadio('fm_submit_report', 'input:checked', site_url('management/createReport'));
```

after I have a full custom jquery script that load in the view, so as to have:

```
$('#fm_submit_report').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var form_data = {
                id_cliente: $('input:checked').val(),
                ci_csrf_token: $.cookie("ci_csrf_token")
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://10.0.0.135/management/createReport.html ',
                type: 'POST',
                async : false,
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(dati, stato){
                    $('#tabs').tabs('select',4);
                    alert('Creazione report per il cliente scelto');
                    console.log('stato: '+stato+'   dati ricevuti: '+dati);
                    $('#create_report').html(dati);
                    alert('Fine caricamento');
                },
                error: function(xhr) {

                var message = 'Errore nell\'invio del form: ';
                var status = xhr.status;
                var text = xhr.statusText;

                message += status + ': ' + text;

                $('<div class="error"/>').text(message).
                appendTo(form);

                }
            });
            return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [CodeIgniter Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) (see very bottom) `$this->load->view()` has a third parameter:

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending
>   it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data
>   in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return
>   data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.

You also have a typo in your code FYI.

Use this instead:

```
$htmlcode=$this->load->view('create_report', $data, TRUE);
echo $htmlcode;
```

Comment: yes, but I see the same result ... the return of JQuery AJAX is the entire page in html, instead of the piece of html code (the form)

Comment: What does `views/create_report.php` contain? This is what is going to be echoed back to AJAX. If you only need the form, then create `views/the_form.php` include the form HTML and use it, instead.

Comment: The file contain simple html code ... a table, and a form... and is in it /view/management/create_report.php

Comment: If I change  "echo $html", whit echo '<h1>Some text</h1>'; the AJAX return the in the variable dati, the entire page web (instead <h1>Some text</h1>)

Comment: In the controller constructor you are loading the `myclients` library. You sure it's constructor or the `findClientById() `method isn't echoing any HTML? When you say it's echoing the "entire page"... I suspect `create_report.php` contains subsequent calls to `$this->load->view()`... Maybe you should use: `$htmlcode=$this->load->view('management/create_report', $data, TRUE);`

Comment: I used $htmlcode=$this->load->view('management/create_report', $data, TRUE); and have the same result. And have the same result if I replace $htmlcode=$this->load->view('management/create_report', $data, TRUE); with echo 'test';